# MySQL Fulltext (Not) Searching

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a table where there are video data, like "title", "description" etc. I'm trying to write a search engine with MySQL fulltext indexing. The SQL query works with some words but not every word. Here is my SQL query;

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('XXXXXXXXXX' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

where I replace "XXXXXXXX" with the query terms. It works with "otomotiv" but not with "otomoti". Doesn't it have to find "otomoti" if it finds "otomotiv", as "otomoti" is part of the whole word "otomotiv"?

I tried changing the search mode to "IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE" or "WITH QUERY EXPANSION" but still no luck.

Is it normal that MySQL can't find a part of the whole word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform boolean full text search as it supports wildcard operator.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST ('otomoti*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: It works, thanks. So would it be sensible to write AGAINST ('* otomoti *' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as there might be other variations, like "potomotiv"? (Sorry for the asterisks b/c SO change anything between asterisks as bold text).

Comment: No, you can't place asterisk at the beginning of the word. If you want to perform substring search, take a look at "LIKE" operator.

Comment: I thought "LIKE" was slower than "FULLTEXT". If that's true, than I have to stick with FULLTEXT, right? It's discussed at this link too, http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,126294 I'm not sure if it's better to use "LIKE".

Comment: "LIKE" uses indexes only when its argument doesn't start with wildcard operator. FULLTEXT search make its own index by splitting your text into tokens and use it later to perform fast search. If you want your users to find "fish" if they search for "fishing", you need to learn about [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming)